# Custom Membership Provider for asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How i can realise my own Membership Provider for my social network example project where i want to use more extended registration with new fields? Thanks.

Comment: if you search on google for custom membership provider you get a lot of good resources related to this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Membership Providers are not meant for holding user profile details, their purpose is to give your application a mechanism for authentication and user-management** - that's it. Like, Fermin correctly said, create a seperate table with one-to-one relation with your primary membership provider table on its UserId. Given this fact, `you actually don't need a custom membership provider` unless your member provider has to work against a different table with different schema for holding membership details.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the default Memership Provider details and create another table to store the extended registration details that you need to store.

You can then have a foreign key in this new table storing a link to the Membership Provider User table.  You can then link back to this and update,view,insert and of the extra information as and when you need to?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **ProfileProvider** which works with and extends the MembershipProvider. Have a look at this blog from Scott Guthrie: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/10/435038.aspx